# Problem setting breakpoint in a DLL for an attached process using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm working with an Autodesk Fusion 360 AddIn sample "SpurGear". Debugging the AddIn involves attaching to the Fusion 360 process and setting breakpoints in the native C++ DLL. Using Visual Studio 2017 this works as expected, stopping in the debugger at the line with the breakpoint. With the same project and reproduction steps in VS 2019 the debugger does not trigger the breakpoint and flows right past.

The only upgrade changes made to the project by VS 2019 are the addition of WindowsTargetPlatformVersion 10.0 and a PlatformToolset change from v140 to v142.

I'm at a loss to find any new compiler/linker settings required to restore the proper behavior. Perhaps this is a bug in VS 2019?! Any experience getting this debug scenario to work in the new VS?

Comment: Does changing the platforms back to the ones from VS 2017, but still using VS 2019 have any effect?

Comment: After undoing the changes made by VS 2019 (removing the Version 10 line and changing v142 back to v140) it still fails to hit the breakpoint. So it seems to NOT be a problem in the compiler/linker.

Comment: Hi Scott, does the project rebuilds successfully whether using platform Toolset V140 or V142? And what about the result if you open the project in VS2017 and debug it?(I'm wondering if you've done some changes to the solution)

Comment: Hi Lance. I've tried both toolsets in VS 2019 with the same result. The v142 toolset doesn't work in 2017.

Please have a look at my answer/resolution as you may have feedback as to how to force the C++ debugger over Python, if that indeed is the problem. Otherwise I may have actually uncovered a VS 2019 issue. It is not desirable to have to uninstall a feature to debug this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the problem by uninstalling "Python development" from Visual Studio 2019 using Visual Studio Installer > Modify.

I can only speculate that, since Fusion 360 supports Python, VS 2019 somehow sensed that and selected the wrong debugger. If this is the problem, perhaps there's some way to force the C++ debugger to be used?! It is odd that debugging works in VS 2017 where I also have Python development installed.

Comment: Yes, that "sense" feature in fact exists.  VS has to guess which one of the ~dozen debugger engines is most appropriate for the process you selected in the Attach dialog.  Somewhat remarkable that they can detect Python code, but they do try to make it smarter all the time.  You'd click the Select button to override its choice.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you describe in detail exactly what 'Select button' you are referencing? I haven't a clue what you mean. Thanks! Also odd that something has changed this behavior between versions.